# Reference request: the formula $\langle x, [f, g] \rangle = \langle \delta(x), f \otimes g \rangle$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{g}^*$ the dual vector space of $\mathfrak{g}$ which is also a Lie algebra with natural brackets. Let $\delta: U(\mathfrak{g}) \to U(\mathfrak{g}) \otimes U(\mathfrak{g})$ be the comultiplication. It is said that 
\begin{align}
\langle x, [f, g] \rangle = \langle \delta(x), f \otimes g \rangle,
\end{align} 
where $\langle, \rangle$ is the natural pairing on $\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}^*$. Are there some references about this formula? Thank you very much.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra, then $\mathfrak{g}^*$ is a Lie coalgebra. Your formula is the definition of the cobracket on $\mathfrak{g}^*$ (it has nothing to do with the comultiplication on $U(\mathfrak{g})$).

Comment: $\delta: \mathfrak g^* \to \bigwedge^2 \mathfrak g^*$ is also the Lie-Poisson structure on $\mathfrak g^*$.